# is it possible to read the downloaded file from chrome browser using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, browser

I downloaded a text file by a click button functionality, using `Selenium Java`.
then the file is downloaded to a particular location in the system, for example,

> C://myAppfiles.

But I can't access that downloaded folder because of some reason. But I have to read that file while downloading.

How to do it? is it possible to read that file from the `browser(chrome)` using selenium or any other method is available?

Answer (score 0):

so I'd suggest to do the following: 
wait until file download is done completely.

After that- try to list all the files in the given directory: 
**all files inside folder and sub-folder**

```
public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        File curDir = new File(".");
        getAllFiles(curDir);
    }
    private static void getAllFiles(File curDir) {

        File[] filesList = curDir.listFiles();
        for(File f : filesList){
            if(f.isDirectory())
                getAllFiles(f);
            if(f.isFile()){
                System.out.println(f.getName());
            }
        }

    }
```

**files/folder only**

```
public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        File curDir = new File(".");
        getAllFiles(curDir);
    }
    private static void getAllFiles(File curDir) {

        File[] filesList = curDir.listFiles();
        for(File f : filesList){
            if(f.isDirectory())
                System.out.println(f.getName());
            if(f.isFile()){
                System.out.println(f.getName());
            }
        }

    }
```

That will help You to understand if there any files at all (in the given directory).
Dont forget to make paths platform independent (to the folder/ file), like:

```
//platform independent and safe to use across Unix and Windows
File fileSafe = new File("tmp"+File.separator+"myDownloadedFile.txt");
```

Also, You might want to check whether file actually exists via Path methods.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.LinkOption;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Path filePath= Paths.get("C:\\myAppfiles\\downloaded.txt");
    System.out.println("if exists: " + Files.exists(firstPath));

  }
}
```

Additionally, path suggests You to check [some other options on the file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/check.html):

```
The following code snippet verifies that a particular file exists and that the program has the ability to execute the file.

Path file = ...;
boolean isRegularExecutableFile = Files.isRegularFile(file) &
         Files.isReadable(file) & Files.isExecutable(file);
```

Once You face any exception- feel free to post it here. 
Hope this helps You

Comment: Suppose, The downloaded file is in the container, but I have no permission to read from that container, the only option is to read the file while downloading it or is there any mechanism to access the file content from the browser, for example, if I downloaded a text file, then can I access it from the download details of that browser, using any selenium or javascript or any other method.

Comment: Please read this though: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/07/file-downloads-with-selenium-mission-impossible/ .  In this case I'd advise to replace selenim download with simple GET/POST request that is responsible for download.

Comment: @chk, please take a look at the sources here: https://github.com/Ardesco/Ebselen/blob/master/ebselen-core/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/ebselen/customhandlers/FileDownloader.java  , that might be helpful for Your case. Hope this helps and dont hesitate to upvote the answer please (if it helps). Thank You